# Ubuntu upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 failed (interrupted) - cannot access Ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, upgrade, wubi

Ubuntu upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 -> failed (interrupted) and now I want to get my data back. Is there any way, without uninstalling the Wubi?

How it happened:
13.04 decides to download around 1 GB of files (1500+ files). It warned me that it'll take around 1 hour for upgrade and my laptop was at 80% (2 hrs battery)

I decided to take a nap, and forgot to put the laptop on the AC power 
I woke up in the morning to find out the battery had died and the laptop was off.

When I reboot, thankfully it showed me both option of the dual boot. (Win 7 and Ubuntu)
On selecting Ubuntu, it showed **error: NO wubildr** for a split second and then the Ubuntu Purple screen. I wait for 5-7 mins to see there is no activity (hard disk light is not even blinking), just the blank purple screen and then I manually switched off the laptop and restarted in ubuntu and again the same issue.

I want to get my data now, since it's not accessible from Win 7. Is there any way to get it back, also if the wubildr is corrupted, then can I just re-install it without affecting the installed files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `chkdsk /f` from Windows first. Then access your data in the file `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` from Windows through [ext2read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/).

Don't hard power off a Wubi install. Do a [safe reboot instead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses).

Once you have your data you can probably recover the install. If you try to reinstall you will lose all your data because Wubi deletes the old install completely before reinstalling. e.g. by booting in recovery mode and trying to repair packages.

To boot in recovery mode, hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key after selecting *Ubuntu*, and then select *Advanced options*, then the second entry *Recovery mode*.
This should boot to the recovery menu from which you can try: `dpkg Repair broken packages`

If you need more information on any of these steps, comment and I'll add more.

Comment: I am able to access the data in \ubuntu\disks\root.disk through the ext2read program.

Comment: How do I try to recover the install? Steps please.

Comment: dpkg Repair broken packages option returned unable to download security updates. Guess it's not able to connect to Internet since the network is not configured.

Comment: At least I'm happy to get my files back! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an ethernet connection? Wireless doesn't work in recovery mode, but a hard connection should.

Comment: I copied my data from Ubuntu to win 7 and I uninstalled Wubi and reinstalled it again. This time it's properly done. No more issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should always make a live session first of the new version and then if everything works do a clean install.The UPGRADE option it's not working well for everyone.And if you dualboot with windows make sure Windows is installed first on HDD or SSD.